# Multiple Apache server installation and switching through php

Tags: apache

I want to perform load balancing by installing and keeping alive 2 servers on one terminal. I am using php and mysql. Kindly tell me 

1. Is it possible to install 2 apache servers ? if yes, how can i switch between these 2 servers programmatically ? 

2. Should i install 2 apache servers or 2 xampp ??? Coz xampp installation is easier as compared to apache?

Comment: How will you talk to PHP if the webserver is down and why would you redirect to another when you have hit the first? Load balancing is done _before_ you hit the server.

Comment: My concern is to keep both of the servers alive simultaneously. its is not for activating slave when master is down.

Comment: If you are looking for round robin, you are still doing it wrong without something to direct the traffic _before_ it hits either of the servers. Also, if you are looking to have multiple servers on the same machine respond to the same URI, they will need to be on seperate ports, so you will still need to hit the server running on port 80 before you can hit the server running on the other port. Seems extremely illogical in my opinion.